# Bug with Shared element transition with activity no history

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have two activities ActivityA and ActivityB with shared element transition. ActivityA has property `"android:noHistory="true"` in manifest. So when I move from ActivityA to ActivityB with shared element everything works good, but when i press on a back button activity closes but shared element is still visible.

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: When you have moved from A to B you pass the values.So it will be available in Activity B.It will be available even Activity A is closed.